# Cannot get the mysql extension module to load for php 7.0?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I'm installing a template on Php 7.0 / MySQL 5.5 that needs the Mysql extension installed.

This is on Ubuntu 14.04, MySql version 5.5, PHP Version 7.0.7-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Currently, despite having installed mysql-server and mysql-client and php7.0-mysql -- this pre-requisite installation code is still returning false:

> if(!extension_loaded('mysql')){$error = TRUE; echo " Mysql PHP extension missing!";}else{echo " Mysql PHP extension loaded!";}

mysqli is installed successfully, but for some reason Php is not seeing the mysql extension and therefore I cannot proceed with my installation.

The same thing is true on a phpinfo() check -- no MySQL module to be found, instead there is pdo_mysql, mysqlnd, and mysqi.. When I check the active php ini file (in fpm folder) I don't see anything obvious in there either.

What do I need to install or enable to get the Mysql extension showing up??

Comment: The `mysql` extensions have been deprecated and removed from PHP 7 ~ from the manual `"Depending on the version of PHP, there are either two or three PHP APIs for accessing the MySQL database. PHP 5 users can choose between the deprecated mysql extension, mysqli, or PDO_MySQL. PHP 7 removes the mysql extension, leaving only the latter two options."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` extension is deprecated. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php

Your options are:

1) Switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`. Ideally `PDO`, since it supports prepared queries and is becoming the extension of choice for the PHP community.

2) If you have a lot of legacy code, then you're better off remaining with PHP 5.

Comment: `mysqli_*` also supports prepared queries. I recommend trying both, they are both good - each with their own pros and cons.

Comment: The mysql extension isn't just deprecated -- it was deprecated a long time ago, and was removed entirely from the language in PHP v7.

Comment: Well, this template still uses about a thousand mysql_connect() calls.... so I guess I'm installing php 5

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but `mysql` extension is not under the development. It deprecated since PHP 5.5 and was removed in PHP 7.0.

The fathers of `mysql` could just improve `mysql` to the new state but they decided to create MySQL Improved or `mysqli`.

The new things in `mysqli` that `mysql` didn't have:

```
Support for asynchronous queries.
Stored procedures
Parameterized queries
Transactions
Better security model.
```

Probable few more, but I cannot recall all now.